# Writing unit test without mocking framework

Tags: c#, nunit, nsubstitute

I am doing some unit tests with NUnit and NSubstiture.

I have this class:

```
public class Presenter
{
    public Presenter()
    {
    }

    private readonly IView _view;
    public Presenter(IView view)
    {
        _view = view;
        this._view.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }
    private void OnLoaded()
    {
        _view.Render("Hello Word");
    }
}
```

And I have this Interface:

```
public interface IView
{
    event Action Loaded;
    void Render(string text);
}
```

And I have already a unit test with the NSubstiture framework, like this:

```
[Test]
public void ctor_WhenViewIsLoaded_CallsViewRender_WithMockingFramework()
{
    var mockView = Substitute.For<IView>();
    Presenter p = new Presenter(mockView);
    mockView.Loaded += Raise.Event<Action>();
    mockView.Received().Render(Arg.Is<string>(s => s.Contains("Hello World")));
}
```

But now I want for just testing purpose, write the same unit test , but then without the NSubstiture framework:

```
[Test]
public void ctor_WhenViewIsLoaded_CallsViewRender_WithoutMockingFramework()
{
    IView view;
    Presenter MockingVIew = new Presenter(view);
}
```

But how to do this?

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
public class FakePresenter : IView
{
    public event Action Loaded;

    public void Render(string text)
    {
    }
}

[Test]
public void ctor_WhenViewIsLoaded_CallsViewRender_WithoutMockingFramework()
{
    //FakeMockingVIew = new Presenter(view);
    FakePresenter fPresenter = new FakePresenter();
    Presenter p = new Presenter(fPresenter);
    fPresenter.Loaded += Raise.Event<Action>();
    fPresenter.Received();
    Assert.That(fPresenter, Is.EqualTo());
}
```

Comment: create a class the is derived from the interface and use that for the test. it is as simple as that.

Comment: Hi, but what do you mean with that? I already have the class Presenter with dependency injection of IView. Can you give an example? Thank you

Comment: you mocked IVew interface using mocking framework. If you no longer want to use the mocking framework, nothing is stopping you from creating a class derived from IView yourself and using that as the dependency in the test.

Comment: But can you give an example? Thank you

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: But how to write the Assert?

Comment: So can somebody help me? Thank you

Comment: It's help if you explained exactly what you we're trying to test here. The later part of this seems a totally different question to the original one. It also doesn't really make any sense why you want to do what you've already done but "without the mocking framework". This seems pretty pointless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you no longer want to use the mocking framework, nothing is stopping you from creating a class derived from `IView` yourself and using that as the dependency in the test

```
public class MyTestClass {

    public class FakePresenter : IView {
        public event Action Loaded = delegate { };

        public void Render(string text) {
            RenderedText = text;
        }

        public string RenderedText { get; private set; }

        public void Load() {
            Loaded();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ctor_WhenViewIsLoaded_CallsViewRender_WithoutMockingFramework() {
        //Arrange
        var fake = new FakePresenter();
        var subject = new Presenter(fake);
        var expected = "Hello Word";

        //Act
        fake.Load();
        var actual = fake.RenderedText;

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

The above implementation of the dependency exposes a `Load()` method to raise the event for all subscribers and also a `RenderedText` property to capture the text passed into the `Render` method so that an assertion can be made based on the value.

Comment: Oke, thank you, but I don't understand this:  public event Action Loaded = delegate { };

Comment: @SavantKing I did that so that the event wont be null. That way I do not have to do a null check before raising the event. A little trick I pickup up along the way. It's more of a habit now as you can avoid that with `?.` in more recent version of c#

Answer (score 0):

When you used NSubstitute, you had to tell the mock view to raise an event. But since the IView interface doesn't allow you to *trigger* the event, only add an event listener, NSubstitute does a workaroud, by attaching a special event handler, it actually triggers an event (I'm not familiar with NSubstitute, but I assume this is what happens):

```
// Code here says "attact an event handler", but NSubstitute recognizes this 
// special event handler and raises the event to the "real" hanlders instead
mockView.Loaded += Raise.Event<Action>();
```

So when you move away from NSubstitute, you need to actually trigger the event the "correct" way from the fake view class:

```
public class FakeView : IView
{
    private string RenderedText { get; private set; }
    public event Action Loaded;

    public void Render(string text)
    {
        renderedText = text;
    }

    public void RaiseLoaded() {
        if (Loaded != null) Loaded();
    }
}
```

Now you can easily trigger the events from your test:

```
[Test]
public void ctor_WhenViewIsLoaded_CallsViewRender_WithoutMockingFramework()
{
    FakeView view = new FakeView();
    Presenter p = new Presenter(fPresenter);
    view.RaiseLoaded();
    Assert.That(view.RenderedText, Is.EqualTo("Hello World"));
}
```